# How to specify that to build project A another project B has to be built first?

Tags: scala, sbt

Suppose one guy in my company has an sbt project called `commons` that's pretty general-purpose. This project is defined in the traditional sbt way: in the main folder with the build definition in `project/Build.scala` file.

Now some other guy is developing a project called `databinding` that depends on `commons`. We want to define this project in the same way, with `project/Build.scala`.

We have the following directory layout:

```
dev/
  commons/
    src/
      *.scala files here...
    project/
      Build.scala
  databinding/
    src/
      *.scala files here...
    project/
      Build.scala
```

How can I specify that `databinding` requires `commons` to be built first and use the output class files?

I read [Multi-project builds](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Multi-Project.html), and came up with the following for the build definition of `databinding`:

```
object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val root = Project(id = "databinding", base = file(".")) settings (
    // ... omitted
  ) dependsOn (commons)

  lazy val common = Project(id = "commons",
    base = file("../commons")
  )

}
```

Except it doesn't work: sbt doesn't like the `..` and throws an AssertionError. Apparently, `commons` should be a folder inside `databinding`. But these two projects are kept in separate git repositories, which we cannot nest.

How can this dependency be specified properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to define the multi-project in a root project (or whatever name but this one fits well) that will be define in `dev/project/Build.scala`.

```
object RootBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file("."))
    .settings(...)
    .aggregate(commons, databinding)

  lazy val commons = Project(id = "commons", base = file("commons"))
    .settings(...)

  lazy val databinding = Project(id = "databinding", base = file("databinding"))
    .settings(...)
    .dependsOn(commons)
}
```

one more thing, SBT doesn't support `*.scala` configuration files in sub-projects. This means that you will have to migrate the configuration you made on `commons/project/Build.scala` and `databinding/project/Build.scala` into respectively `commons/build.sbt` and `databinding/build.sbt`.

If some of your configuration are not suitable for a `.sbt` definition file, you will have to add them in the root `project/Build.scala`. Obviously, settings defined in root `Build.scala` are available in `*.sbt` files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, David. This seems weird, does it that just because other projects use my project `commons`, it cannot have a full definition in a `.scala` file?

Comment: And, is there an alternative — e.g., adding a resolver that looks up the jars generated by the projects it depends on?

Comment: Regarding your first question, it's an SBT restriction that prevent you to use a `*.scala` file to define sub-projects. I think it's a limitation due to the way SBT merges project definition files. Fortunately, `*.sbt` files will be able to access vals, settings ... from your root project `Build.scala`. You can also consider as you mention it in the second comment to publish your `common` in local (publish-local) for example and the resolver should retrieve it. Be careful to add `isChanging()` to the dependency definition if you want to use a SNAPSHOT system. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, David, this is helpful.

Answer (score 10):

You should use [RootProject](http://harrah.github.com/xsbt/latest/api/sbt/RootProject.html) (in case of referring to root project of another project) or [ProjectRef](http://harrah.github.com/xsbt/latest/api/sbt/ProjectRef.html) (in case of referring to subproject of another project).

Here is a sample of using RootProject:

```
       lazy val commons = RootProject(file("../commons"))
       lazy val root = Project(id = "databinding", base = file(".")) settings (...) dependsOn (commons)
```

And here is the sample for using ProjectRef

```
       lazy val commons = ProjectRef(file("../commons"), "sub-project")
       lazy val root = Project(id = "databinding", base = file(".")) settings (...) dependsOn (commons)
```

Comment: Is this `RootProject` new? Does this new API invalidate David's recommended solution?

Comment: It seems so. No, but I'd say it's a bit simpler

Comment: I can't myself understand how the approved answer could have worked for the OP without the migration that defeats the purpose of the two projects being independent. They won't after the migration because of the root project.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two separate projects, and just publish one of them locally, adding it as a normal library dependency to the other.