# Sbt Multi-Module - using some project as module in another project

Tags: scala, sbt, git-submodules

I have sbt project, `commonLib` which builds fine as a standalone project. What I want to do now, is to make this project a git-submodule of other project and add it as additional module. The resulting layout should look like following:

```
+ project
+ src
+ commonLib
+---- project
+---- src
```

How can I correctly add such sbt project as a module of root project? Is this even possible? Putting all modules in one repository is not an option for me, since this commonLib is also used by other projects, and we want to make collaborative development of this module as smooth as possible.

P.S. Using repository for releases on every commit in commonLib does not feels like a good solution, and we can't stuck to at least something like releases of common library because development is very active.

Comment: Do you want the `commonsLib` checked out as a part of your normal project? If that's just conceptual idea, then you should be good with defining a `RootProject` and a dependency on it. [See the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Dormant/Full-Configuration.html#project-relationships). Sbt will check it out automatically and build for you.

Comment: commonLib itself is usual sbt project that has its own git repository. What I want to do here is to add it as git submodule to be able to manage its state from within this root project that depends on this lib. The link to the documentation you gave looks interesting, I'll check it out and see if it helps

Comment: Cool, let me know if it works for you, and if so I'll make it a proper answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In sbt, how do I specify a project dependency on another, possibly independent sbt project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330149/in-sbt-how-do-i-specify-a-project-dependency-on-another-possibly-independent-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the documentation link from *lpiepiora*, I ended up doing it like this in my Build.scala for root project:

```
lazy val commonLib = ProjectRef(file("commonLib"), "commonLib")
lazy val root = Project("myProject", file(".")).dependsOn(commonLib)
```

, where commonLib is a name of project mentioned in Build.scala of commonLib sbt project.

If you only need root project of subdirectory with standalone sbt project just use RootProject instead of ProjectRef.